# python code coverage error cat: /ade_info.vmd: No such file or directory

Tags: python, code-coverage

I am trying to learn code coverage in python. I wrote "Hello World" programme.

**Hello.py**

```
#!//usr/bin/python

print "Hello World"
```

When I executed it using coverage like below.

```
coverage run test.py
```

Getting below error.

```
cat: /ade_info.vmd: No such file or directory
/usr/local/packages/dbtest/CodeCoverage/src/cli/coverage/bin/coverage_3.0: 
line 4: [: =: unary operator expected
Initializing coverage command line 3.1
[WARNING]: coverage tool can only be run from viewplease enter the view run    
again
====================================================
Coverage Command Line -3.1
Usage : coverage [help|recomp|link|show|runtest|restore|ccvhelp]
For help, use 'coverage <command> -help' option
```

Any idea why getting above error?

Comment: You are running something different than coverage.py.  I don't know what your "coverage" command is, but it's not coverage.py.

Comment: Thanks @Ned. You are correct its not coverage.py. Its something else.

Comment: @RishiBansal, Can you please explain how you have solved this issue? As I'm also facing the same issue.

Comment: @SaifBaig give full path of coverage command, it is taking some other coverage file.